# ViewController title not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, master-detail

I'm creating an iPad app using the master-detail application template. In my MasterViewController.m file I have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.detailViewController.title = @"testing";

}
```

When tapping on a cell in the tableView, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your detailViewController? Is it nil?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.title = @"testing";` ?

Comment: Log your DetailVIew and see what is the result, how do you initialize the detailView. When I work with master-detail i rely heavily on delegation, its a better solution to set objects from master to detail and vice versa.

Comment: Does the detailViewController have a nav bar? If it doesn't you probably meant to set the title of your MasterViewController.

Comment: I logged the detailViewController and it's null.

Comment: In that case your detailViewController is never being initialized, hence you are not seeing any chance.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project using the master-detail application template to see what happens.

On MasterViewController.m file, the template creates the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }
}
```

If I add the following line into the above method, self.detailViewController changed the title on the navigationView, normally:

```
self.detailViewController.title = @"custom title";
```

Although, this only works when running the app on iPad, because `self.detailViewController` is created and is visible on the screen through the `self.splitViewController`.

When you run this app on the iPhone, `self.detailViewController` is only created after you click on the cell. Therefore, `self.detailViewController` will be `nil` inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. The action of tapping on the cell will trigger a Segue Push action, that will create the `DetailViewController`.